# EmberJS: Usar ESLint en lugar de JSHint

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Estoy usando `EmberJS` v1.13 y actualmente al ejecutar `ember test` utiliza `JSHint` para detectar posibles errores en el código y necesito indicarle a `Ember` que utilice en su lugar `ESLint`.

¿Alguna idea sobre que debo hacer?

Answer (score 3):

podrías utilizar las siguientes herramientas:

1. Para el navegador: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi

2. Usando Visual Studio Code, le agregas una extension: ve al marketplace e instala el cli de Ember (te ayudara)

3. Instalando Ember CLI ESLint https://github.com/jonathanKingston/ember-cli-eslint

```js
// ember-cli-build.js (or Brocfile.js on older versions of ember-cli)

var path = require('path');
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
// `npm install --save-dev js-string-escape`
var jsStringEscape = require('js-string-escape');

var app = new EmberApp({
  eslint: {
    testGenerator: eslintTestGenerator
  }
});

function render(errors) {
  if (!errors) { return ''; }
  return errors.map(function(error) {
    return error.line + ':' + error.column + ' ' +
      ' - ' + error.message + ' (' + error.ruleId +')';
  }).join('\n');
}

// Qunit test generator
function eslintTestGenerator(relativePath, errors) {
  var pass = !errors || errors.length === 0;
  return "import { module, test } from 'qunit';\n" +
    "module('ESLint - " + path.dirname(relativePath) + "');\n" +
    "test('" + relativePath + " should pass ESLint', function(assert) {\n" +
    "  assert.ok(" + pass + ", '" + relativePath + " should pass ESLint." +
    jsStringEscape("\n" + render(errors)) + "');\n" +
   "});\n";
}

// Mocha test generator
function eslintTestGenerator(relativePath, errors) {
  var pass = !errors || errors.length === 0;
  return "import { describe, it } from 'mocha';\n" +
    "import { assert } from 'chai';\n" +
    "describe('ESLint - " + path.dirname(relativePath) + "', function() {\n" +
    "  it('" + relativePath + " should pass ESLint', function() {\n" +
    "    assert.ok(" + pass + ", '" + relativePath + " should pass ESLint." +
    jsStringEscape("\n" + render(errors)) + "');\n" +
   "  });\n});\n";
}
```

Que tengas un bonito, día éxitos con el desarrollo!

Comment: Gracias, las primeras dos no me ayudan porque necesito deshabilitar jshint cuándo ejecuto  `ember test` (jshint se ejecuta en el core y necesito indicarle que no lo haga y que en su lugar ejecute eslint). La tercera me puede ser de ayuda pero me parece muy compleja, habrá una solución más simple? Al final creo que es mejor trabajar con jshint porque ya viene integrado con ember. Sin embargo, seguiré buscando otra solución.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar [ember-cli-eslint](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-eslint), instalando:

ESLint 3 (para Node 4 o mayor):

```
ember install ember-cli-eslint@3
```

ESLint 2 (for Node 0.10 o mayor):

```
ember install ember-cli-eslint@2
```

Después borrás `jshint` corriendo:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev ember-cli-jshint
```

Y borrás todos los archivos `.jshintrc` que hayan quedado en el proyecto.